# Unsubscribe link to opt out of email in professional edition

Tags: process-builder, automated-process, salesforce-flow

I have a professional edition Salesforce Instance. I was searching for ways to provide an option to contacts and leads to opt out of salesforce emails. I would like to create a link which can be inserted in a email template but i am unable to find any solution. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What research or options have you looked at so far? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use opt out link on mass mails, Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmOBUAZ/opt-out-link).

However there are many free AppExchange tools to use unsubscribe link [1](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMkfNUAT&tab=d) (Unsubscribe Link), [2](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YDZEA2&tab=d) (Unsubscribe opt-out) and these tools are compatible with Enterprise, Unlimited, Force.com and Developer editions.